# Make colorbar compatible with gradient bar plot values

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to make the values I plot to be compatible with the colorbar values. How can I do this? See more details below.

y1, y2, y3 values are : [-1.7  -1.62 -1.53 -1.43 -1.32 -1.2  -1.09 -0.97 -0.85],
 [-1.43 -1.28 -1.09 -0.88 -0.66 -0.44 -0.21  0.03  0.27], [-3.65 -3.58 -3.48 -3.38 -3.27 -3.16 -3.04 -2.92 -2.8 ]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9.6,6), dpi=300, linewidth=3.0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(311)
y1 = y.transpose()   #y should be the first data I gave out in the beginning
gradient = [ y1,y1 ]
plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'))
ax.set_xticklabels(data[list[1]])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
y2 = y.transpose()  #y should be the second data I gave out in the beginning
gradient = [ y2,y2 ]
plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'))
ax2.set_xticklabels(data[list[5]])

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
y3 = y.transpose()  #y should be the third data I gave out in the beginning
gradient = [ y3,y3 ]
plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'))
ax3.set_xticklabels(data[list[9]])

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'),norm=plt.Normalize(-6.39,9.29))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm,ax=[ax,ax2,ax3])
#fig.set_tight_layout(True)       #how can I use this? If I use this it generates a warning and the plot overlaps
plt.savefig('CuxOxi.png',dpi=300,format='png', orientation='landscape')
```

[image]

As you can see from the graph, the colorbar ranges from -6.39 to 9.29. Each subplot ranges only a fraction of the complete colorbar range. How can I make for example -1.62 to -1.2 to have the color range as defined in the colorbar (which is mostly red)

Answer (score 2):

In each plot, you can add the `vmin` and `vmax` options to the `plt.imshow` function in order to set the color scale min and max for that plot.  You can define these to be the same for each plot so that they all have the same scale.

```
vmin = -6
vmax = 9

plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'),vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
```

Comment: If you consider [-1.7 -1.62 -1.53 -1.43 -1.32 -1.2 -1.09 -0.97 -0.85] dataset, the xticklabels don't span the whole range from -1.7 to -0.85. Rather I see the range of xticklabels from -1.62, -1.53, -1.43, -1.32, -1.2. If I remove `ax.set_xticklabels(data[list[c]])`, I see the plot with ticks of 0,2,4,6,8. So, looks like only the 5 data from the dataset are plotted and rest are left out. How do you treat the ticklabels correctly?